# Entity Framework 6 code first: setting unicode to false for string properties

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

In my model i have some entities decorated with StringLength attribute:

```
[StringLength(128)]    
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

Also i have disable unicode for all string properties this way:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Properties<string>().Configure(p => p.IsUnicode(false));            
}
```

The problem is that all string properties decorated with the mentioned attribute are ignoring this setting when generating the database schema, producing nvarchar datatype for the corresponding database columns. 
What is the correct way to disable unicode in this cases?

Comment: I see the same thing. Probably a bug in the new `PropertyConventionConfiguration` API.

Comment: Thanks @GertArnold, any workarround for this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Seems to be a bug (or omission) in the new `PropertyConventionConfiguration` API. The following configuration does work, so it can serve as a work-around:

```
modelBuilder.Properties<string>().Configure(x => x.HasColumnType("VARCHAR"));
```

Comment: See the issue. Fixed in 6.1.0 (currently in beta).

Comment: Your solution works well, but the paperwork from MSDN shows his method as the preferred option. This a bug? And was it resolved?

Comment: It's not Bug, in some Unicode language [StringLength(128)]  require more than 128 byte, so the model created the column with nvarchar datatype.