# Database handling using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have two questions for database handling using Entity Framework. I am using SQL Server 2012/14 web api 2 (VS 2012/13) but it doesn't matter because my question is regarding code first approach for EF6. In code first approach if the table does not exist that EF creates it for you (EF's awesome feature).
**1.)** Usually when EF creates a table, it uses nvarchar for string datatype but I need to use varchar. How can I specify that in EF? (Also for other datatypes?)
**2.)**  Also I need to create stored procedure using EF (if it does not exist in DB). And also how can I invoke it from EF? Stored Procedure takes input parameter and gives output records.
In case of any change in model or logic, it should be reflected automatically in DB. **[Very Important]**
**Request:** Please keep the understanding level of your explanation to be Super Easy. I have just saw some YouTube videos and trying to understand it and implement it on my project. But I don't want to just copy code, I want to understand it so please kindly provide explanation for each line. Multiple solution will be appreciated. (I mean Data Annotation and Fluent API both)
**My Last Option:** I was thinking of creating script and executing it in "up" function (where migration happens and creates all SQL object) But issue with that approach is that if there is any change in my model, I have to reflect the same changes in that script too as it is hard coded. I am going to use this option when I have no other choice left. I haven't tried this option yet so I might be completely wrong about it.
***Thanks in advance.***

Comment: You can configure EF to use varchar by default: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22120007/entity-framework-6-code-first-setting-unicode-to-false-for-string-properties

Answer (score 0):

1) If you want to specify the database type to be used in the actual column of your table, here is the code (using Fluent API) for it:

```
modelbuilder.Entity<Department>()   
    .Property(p => p.Name)   
    .HasColumnType("varchar");
```

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617#1.10

2) If you want Entity Framework to generate the script that would create your desired stored procedure, have a look at this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn468673. I don't think it would be a good idea to copy the source code from there and paste it over here, so if you have any specific questions, feel free to ask.

If you want to create the stored procedure script yourself and then invoke it using Entity Framework, then have a look at this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj557860. **Note**: this option tends to have a maintenance cost associated to it. But it is worth doing it if the stored procedure generated by Entity Framework is not as efficient as your version of how the stored procedure should be written as.

Again please feel free to ask any specific questions here.